# preg_replace remove http: from link

Tags: php

Trying to retrieve data from the database to put into a YouTube frame

When a person submits their link to their video, they send it as `http://ww...` I then need to convert that when it displays in the iframe as `//ww...` so how do I remove the `http:` from their links using preg_replace?

Comment: Why do you even need to remove the http: part?

Comment: There are 4 answers, 3 are upvoted, please select one so this does not show up in unanswered section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want regex like this:

`$new = preg_replace( '/^https?:\/\//', '', $url );`

That will ensure `http://` and `https://` are removed.

`^` = start of the string
`?` = previous character optional

If your site is ONLY allowing `http://` then @Aurelio is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ltrim**

```
$newUrl = ltrim($url, 'http:');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.. `preg_replace( "#^[^:.]*[:]+#i", "", $URL );`

you can try this code below:

```
<?php
 $url = "http://youtube.com"; 
 $url = preg_replace( "#^[^:.]*[:]+#i", "", $url); 
 echo $url;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same goal with `str_replace()` that is faster:

```
$newUrl = str_replace('http:, '', $url);
```